# PHP: Assigning values to a variable inside IF statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, variable-assignment

I was wondering if i could assign values to a variable inside an IF statement. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
    if ((count($newArray) = array("hello", "world")) == 0) {
        // do something
    }
?>
```

So basically i want assign the array to the $newArray variable, then count newArray and check to see if it is an empty array.

I know i can do this on several lines but just wondered if i could do it on one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(count($newArray = array("Hello", "world")) == 0) {
    ....
}
```

I'd advice against this though, as it makes your code less readable. And highly illogical too as you *know* that the array in question contains two values. But perhaps you have something else in mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can, like so:

```
if(count($ary = array(1,2,3)))
```

Doing a `var_dump` of `$ary` gives:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use count inside the if statement, because an empty array is considered to be false in PHP. See [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

So your code can look like this:

```
if (!$newArray = array("hello", "world")) {
    echo "newArray is empty";
}
```